# SQL mirror view to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, synchronization

Previously I had a SQL Server agent job running every night inserting today's findate into a table from a view. But I didn't realize that in the table there are also findates for next month so it doesn't keep up. I tried looking at joins and unions but I can't figure it out. Can anyone tell me what kind of query I should be looking at to add newly added rows from the view to the table. Previously I had a query as following

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vw_view
WHERE FinDate = FinDate
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `in the table` which table? `there are also findates` what are those, and why do they affect the query? `for next month so it doesn't keep up` you want rows even before they have been inserted in the table? You need to be much clearer: what is the table and view definition, and what exactly are you trying to do? Better question: why do you want to insert rows from a view into a table, why can you not just have another view referring to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can keep it in sync with the following query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table
SELECT FROM dbo.view e where
not exists (SELECT FROM dbo.table WHERE id= e.id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should specify the column to be added

```
Insert Into dbo.MyTable (Col1, Col2,...)
Select Col1, Col2, ...
From dbo.MyView
Where FinDate = FinDate
```

Comment: This doesn't work because for example, rows with the date of tomorrow won't be added

Comment: True, but thats not an answer to the question. Just a tip for writing good SQL.